# Управление Constraint Layout из кода

Tags: java, android

Как управлять Margins из кода элементами из Constraint Layout.

```
    final ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(100 + w, 100 + w);
    layoutParams.setMargins(rand.getLocation(500),rand.getLocation(500),rand.getLocation(700),rand.getLocation(700));
    iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    rootLayout.addView(iv, layoutParams);
```

И в итоге Margins не задаются, а блоки появляются в начале (слева,сверху).

Comment: попробуйте в таком ключе задавать layoutParams.rightMargin = 100;

Answer (score -1):

Прикрепите view:

```
layoutParams.startToStart = R.id.button; layoutParams.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
```